# How to add -Ddb2.jcc.charsetDecoderEncoder=3 in spark-submit and how to ensure whether these properties set in driver

Tags: apache-spark, db2

got Cp1027 error in IBM driver, the non-UTF-8 character is not reading by the db2jcc driver.

Comment: **Error log:**    java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: Cp1027
     at java.nio.charset.Charset.forName(Charset.java:531)
     at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.x.<init>(x.java:20)
       at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.k4.bd(k4.java:774)
     at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.k4.executeQuery(k4.java:739)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:62)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation.<init>(JDBCRelation.scala:114)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the [Customization of IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ configuration properties](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_cjvcfgpr.html) article.
You may place the `DB2JccConfiguration.properties` file containing `db2.jcc.charsetDecoderEncoder=3` row to your classpath to make the driver use it.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for your response. I provide those properties through classpath even value is not retrieving from DB.   my spark-submit command provided below.                                                                         
      spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client --num-executors 20 --executor-memory 60g  --executor-cores 10 --conf "spark.executor.heartbeatInterval=10000" --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Ddb2.jcc.charsetDecoderEncoder=3" --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Ddb2.jcc.charsetDecoderEncoder=3"

Comment: What's the exact DB2 driver you use and what's the exact error text / stack trace?

Comment: version of jar :- db2jcc4-4.24.92.jar


I can see the output those values are set in classpath too: FYI

  command:
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/lib/native:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" \ 
      {{JAVA_HOME}}/bin/java \ 
      -server \ 
      -Xmx20480m \ 
      '-Ddb2.jcc.charsetDecoderEncoder=3' \ 
      -Djava.io.tmpdir={{PWD}}/tmp \ 
      '-Dspark.history.ui.port=18081' \ 
      -Dspark.yarn.app.container.log.dir=<LOG_DIR> \ 
      -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill %p' \

Comment: 19/12/27 12:07:58 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 0
java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: Cp1027
 at java.nio.charset.Charset.forName(Charset.java:531)

Comment: But it was working in Web application and it's not working spark with cluster and I can assure somewhere I am missing to provide a right command.

Comment: What's the JRE you use with your spark cluster? Is this Oracle JRE? If yes, then Cp1027 is not supported according to the [Supported Encodings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html) link.